# Which variant of Rummy requires a last round of a "run of seven" and a set of three?

Tags: identify-this-game, rummy

I've heard of a variant of Rummy with a “run of seven” and a set of three involved. What is that variant and how do I play it?

Comment: Phase 10 has things like a "run of 7", but not a "run of 7 + set of 3".

Comment: @jrw32982 it's possible in the version I described, when a player lays a 7-set and during subsequent play lays a 3-set to void their hand. AFAIR we went from one 7 to one 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be referring to the game [**Conquian**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conquian) which is a variant of [Contract Rummy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_rummy).

In the first round, players must lay a [Meld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meld_(cards)) of 3 cards. A Meld is  either a Set or a Run (Set is 3 cards or more with equal rank, e.g. (8♠ 8♣ 8♥), A Run is ascending cards belonging to the same suit, e.g. 8♠ 9♠ 10♠)

The Contracts progress through two melds of three (laid at the same time), then one meld of four cards and another of three, etc. One of the later contracts is a meld of 3 and a Run of 7.  There are many variations in the way the game is played.

---

**In more detail, this is the version I play**:

- Two decks of cards might be needed. The number of players can be two or more.
- The dealer shuffles the deck, and deals 7 cards face down to each player, lays the deck face down, and turns over one card to begin the discard pile.
- **Two**s are wildcards, which need not follow suit in a Run.
- On each turn:

  1. The active player must either draw one card from the top of the deck, or as many cards as they wish from the discard pile, which must be consecutive cards including the top card.
  2. Then, if they can lay **all** the required melds, they do so.
  3. If they have already placed their melds, they can place more melds (of any size), or add to the melds of any player, or exchange any player's wildcard **two**s from their melds, replacing them with the card they represent (if they are holding it). They may then use the **two** immediately to make and lay more melds.
  4. Finally the player may optionally discard *one* card face up onto the discard pile, and their turn ends.
- A Run may go 'over the top', i.e. QKA23 and must be the same suit (except **two**s).

The object is to lay all one's cards. The round ends when the first player does so.

Each player then counts up the score of the cards remaining in their hand (court cards score 10, **two** scores 15).

After the last round, the player with the lowest score is the winner.

The game ends when a player complete the last contract. The Contracts we play are:

- 1 three, 2 threes
- 1 four, 1 four + 1 three, 2 fours
- 1 five, 1 five + 1 three, 1 five + 1 four
- 1 six, 1 six + 1 three ... etc.
- 1 seven
- 1 ten

Comment: The name we know this game by is mentioned in the link. It's a homophone of Conquian, with no negative association intended, yet I avoided using it.